# Lambda calculus with Prolog

Tags: parsing, lambda, prolog, nlp, logic

I'm doing past exam questions for my Symbolic AI course. One of the questions is this:

Show the interpretation that the grammar and lexicon would assign to
`Every man will die`
[14 marks]

```
[cat=s, meaning=VP:NP]
        ==> [[cat=np, meaning=NP], [cat=vp, meaning=VP]].

[cat=np, meaning=DET:N]
         ==> [[cat=det, meaning=DET], [cat=noun, meaning=N]].

[cat=vp, meaning=V] ==> [[cat=verb, meaning=V]].

[cat=vp, meaning=AUX:VP] ==> [[cat=aux, meaning=AUX], [cat=vp, meaning=VP]].

lexEntry(’every’,
        [cat=det, 
        meaning=lambda(P, lambda(Q, forall(X, (P:X => Q:X))))]).

lexEntry(’man’, [cat=noun, meaning=lambda(U, man(U))]).

lexEntry(’will’, [cat=aux, meaning=lambda(A, lambda(B, future(A:B)))]).

lexEntry(’die’, 
        [cat=verb,
        meaning=lambda(B, B:(lambda(X, exists(Z, die(Z) & patient(Z, X)))))]).
```

I've been told that the correct answer for this is

```
future(forall(X,man(X) => exists(Z,die(Z) & patient(Z,X))))
```

But I have no idea how to get that result. Could someone show me the steps to achieve that or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: What Prolog dialect is this? I cannot recognise this syntax.